# How to parse this JSON with strange array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft's JSON parser to parse results from an external system (the external system is not .net, so they are using a different serialization library).

The JSON string looks kind of funny to me.  The endpoint is for /clients, but instead of returning an array of client resources, it returns a named object that contains an array.  Like this:

```
{"Client": [{"ClientId":"TheId"}]}
```

If I try to deserialize that into a client array, it fails with an exception:

```
Client[] clients = serializer.Deserialize<Client[]>(aReaderWithTheJson)
```

The exception:

> *Cannot deserialize the current JSON object ... To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type*

I have gotten it to deserialize successfully by creating an artificial wrapper class for my target object like so:

```
class ClientArray 
{
  public Client[] Client {get;set;}
}

// then deserialize:
var clientWrapper = serializer.Deserialize<ClientArray>(theReader);
var client = clientWrapper.Client[0];
```

My question though:  While this works, Is there some feature of JSON.net that I don't know about that I should look into (some kind of serialization helper, or an attribute that I could decorate my DTO with?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The JSON you have is well formatted JSON. Nothing funny about it.

It's returning an array of client resources packaged/wrapped in a root object.

```
{"Client": [{"ClientId":"TheId"}]}
```

which resolve to this...

```
public class Client
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject // Same as you wrapper
{
    public IList<Client> Client { get; set; }
}
```

when placed in a JSON deserializer like http://jsonutils.com

Just like you eventually figured out by using your Wrapper object.

```
var clientWrapper = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
var clients = clientWrapper.Client;
```

This looks exactly like what you have in your question. There is nothing else really for you to do if that is how the external system is providing the data.